# diskio/diskiograph in Conky only understands physical device names?

Tags: conky

In case this is so, it can be a huge downer in modern Linux distros, since the device names are very often assigned arbitrarily.
So if you have no more than two HDDs in your system, but two USB flash drives sticking in their ports, things might look like this after bootup:

```
/dev/sda .. HDD #1
/dev/sdb .. USB flash drive #1
/dev/sdc .. USB flash drive #2
/dev/sdd .. HDD #2
```

I have searched high and low and tried various hacks for my `.conkyrc` to no avail. It just does not seem to work.

I even thought about "creating" the format required for conky by executing a system command, but even this failed. In `bash`, this can be achieved by

```
$ basename $(readlink /dev/disk/by-label/mydisklabel)
```

Though conky DOES allow execution of system commands, it seems that in {diskio}/{diskiograph} options, this is not possible.
So the following will NOT work:

```
${diskio /dev/${execp basename $(readlink /dev/disk/by-label/mydisklabel)}}
```

Neither would the variant with the UUID work (not shown here).
Has anyone of you guys ever managed to "teach" this to conky? It's so insanely versatile, but it's almost unbelievable that (compared to the good old days) `udev` and friends will no longer keep drives in a certain order, but scramble them again on each bootup sequence, while tools (GKrellM is none the better!) stubbornly insist on physical drive/device names.

Comment: In Ubuntu 20.04 using `${diskio_read /dev/disk/by-id/<some-disk-id>}` works.

Answer (score 2):

To use the any of the `/dev/disk/by-??` paths in full, as follows:

```
${diskio /dev/disk/by-label/mydisklabel}
```

you need to have `conky` version 1.9.1 or later, which is known as `conky-ng`.  From Fedora 20 onwards, it's available as the `conky` package. Ubuntu is still using the older version (as of Ubuntu 14.04) therefore you'll need to compile `conky-ng`. The latter is also true for Arch Linux.

The `Disk IO` line in the screenshot below shows it working with a `by-label` entry in `.conkyrc` while `find .` is running in a terminal.

[image: Conky running with disk-by-label]

Note that there should not be a space between the last character of the path and the closing brace (`}`) otherwise `conky` will complain of path not found.

Comment: Thanks for bearing with me...I think the problem is that in my case, `/dev/sdc6` is in fact a NTFS formatted partition, let's call it `/dev/disk/by-label/videos` for example, which on `ls -l` points to `--> ../../sdc6`. This is assigned to `/media/videos`, which, of course, isn't accepted either by conky. My (shortened) version line is `Conky 1.9.0 compiled 2014-02-19 for Linux 3.2.0-54-generic (i686)`. I can't seem to believe that I really need to upgrade to 1.9.1 to get this working.

Comment: You're a marvel, thank you so much! So I will need to replace conky by conky-ng (a fork, see https://github.com/Tucos/conky-ng). I just don't understand why this hasn't been implemented yet in the "standard" conky. It's such an essential feature to have in `udev` times.

Comment: I agree.  It seems that Ubuntu and Arch are using the older version.  I've added the info to the answer and propose that we tidy up these comments/chit-chat by deleting.

Comment: Proposal dismissed! This _isn't_ chit-chat. I was even rather frowning upon getting this "chit chat warning" by SE. It's IMHO uncalled-for, and I felt treated like an immature teen.---Back to conky: Unfortunately this only works for `diskio`+label symlinks, but not with `diskiograph`. That is, when used with the latter, it will not complain about path not found, but it won't display anything either in the graph. Doing the same with the physical path did work instantly, though.

Comment: Well, my whole line is `${diskiograph /dev/disk/by-uuid/1234567890ABCDEF 15, 130 828282 7f8ed3 0.1 -l}`. Since there are a decent lot of parameters following the UUID, it's only natural that there is a space after it. :) `diskio` is not `diskiograph`; the former does not take any parameters.

Comment: I have: `${diskiograph /dev/disk/by-uuid/60fc9b67-a8a7-4183-a827-aa644f0e0680}`. Presumably, it uses some reasonable defaults if you omit the options.

Comment: And again you're right!! Once I omit the parameters, I get ugly colors and wrong height, but yes it works! However, I can't accept this. I ought to file a bug report that the parameters will actually "kill" the graph when no physical device name is given.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the source code, it seems that name resolution for symlinks is done in a relative way. The program uses readlink(2) where it should use realpath(3). When using `/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-*` it resolves to `../../sd?` which fails if conky's current working directory isn't `/dev/disk/by-id`.

To use label, you can use `label:some_disk_label` and it should work. To get by-id/by-uuid, the author would have to accept my pull request at https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky/pull/238 in which I converted diskio path resolution method to use realpath(3).